# How can I describe the binary layout of a data structure in C++ or a Interface Definition Language?

Tags: c++, linux, serialization

Consider the following struct:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct Measurement {
    int     type; // 0: temperature, 1: humidity
    double value;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

This code both defines the binary layout of a `Measurement` unambiguously in memory and makes it easy to serialize/deserialize to/from memory:

```
void writeValueToBuffer(Measurement& measurement, unsigned char* dst) {
    unsigned char* src = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&measurement);
    std::memcpy(dst, src, sizeof(Measurement));
}

void readValueFromBuffer(unsigned char* src, Measurement& measurement) {
    unsigned char* dst = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&measurement);
    std::memcpy(dst, src, sizeof(Measurement));
}
```

However consider the case where I have N measurements.
Logically I may represent this as:

```
struct Measurements {
    std::vector<Measurement> measurements;
};
```

In this case the binary layout of the data structure is ambiguous.

In a project I work on I need to describe the binary layout of a data structure that will be used by a project partner and write this data structure to shared memory.
The data structure is dynamic in size like the example above.

Ideally I would like to describe the binary layout in C++ unambiguously in a manner that makes it easy to write serialize/deserialize code.

Failing that I would like to describe the binary layout in an interface definition language.
I may then use auto generated serialization code on my end.

Ideally I should make no requirements on project partner on how they will deserialize the data or what language they will program in.

Comment: ASN.1 might be a good start, to do that completely language agnostic. A more modern approach is to use something like Google protocol buffers.

Comment: You have to have requirements on the binary layout. These requirements can be made by you or the parties you interface with. One way would be to refrain from things like `#pragma pack` and require the `Measurement` structure to by 16 bytes in size and require certain offsets of the data members by `static_assert(sizeof(Measurement) == 16); static_assert(offsetof(Measurement, type) == 0); ...` and so on. If certain compilers try to layout the structure differently, work around if with `#if defined(__GNUC__) ... #elif defined(...)` etc.

Comment: But in the end you'll probably make your life easier by going with existing solutions like googles protocol buffers or similar, like @πάνταῥεῖ suggested.

Comment: @chrysante there's even stuff to [support ASN.1](https://www.asnlab.com/asncpp/overview.html#:~:text=oriented%20programming%20techniques.-,The%20ASN.,In%20addition%20to%20the%20ASN.), [2](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c), [3](http://tysonite.github.io/asn1-compiler/), etc. But interacting with protocol implementations in other languages, Google protocol buffers is certainly the better choice.

Comment: @Andy _"I can make no requirements on project partner on how they will deserialize the data or what language they will program in."_ Then ASN.1 is the _lingua franca_ to do that.